# How to handle dependencies between objects/components

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, c++, dependencies

Im currently working on a college project on the simulation of magnetic interactions of particles, see [physical simulation: design thoughts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/442542/physical-simulation-design-thoughts/442546#442546).

Right now im starting to code my system according to this design: [image: class diagram]

However, I'm realizing that I haven't thought the communication between my `PhysicsWorld` and my `PhysicsSystems` through. My basic idea behind this design was seperating the properties of the `physObjects` from their behaviour to keep the design structured and flexible.

But to calculate the behaviour, I need access to the properties of the `physObjects`. So my first idea was including a list of every `physObject` in the `PhysicsSystems` base class. Though I think this meaning Ill duplicate the list for every derived specific `PhysicsSystem` isn't a good idea.

The other option would be having the `PhysicsWorld` handle the list of `physObjects`, which seems more intuitive since the `PhysicsWorld` should probably know about which objects it includes anyway. I like this option way better, I'm struggling to find a solution on how to ive that list of objects to the `PhysicsSystems` though.

Would I just pass that list as an argument in the `update()` method. So like `update(objects&, timestep)`?

Edit: I'm coding this in C++ btw, for anyone wondering. I know there are `friend` fnctions and this was actually my first approach to handle any dependencies. However my professor said this isnt a good approach. Can anyone explain the reason why?

PS:
This being my first OOP project, I know my design isn't flawless. I've made small changes already not represented in the class diagram yet, like including setters. But my main concern is how to make the connection between `physObjects` and `PhysicsSystems`.

I'm grateful for any input, thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

> The other option would be having the `PhysicsWorld` handle the list of `physObjects`, which seems more intuitive since the `PhysicsWorld` should probably know about which objects it includes anyway. I like this option way better, I'm struggling to find a solution on how to give that list of objects to the `PhysicsSystems` though.

If you define the responsibility of `PhysicsWorld` as "To represent the state of the physical world at a particular point in time", then it is natural that `PhysicsWorld` handles the list of `physObjects`.

And with that definition, you can invert the relation between `PhysicalWorld` and `PhysicsSystem` in your model. The world just represents static information (the state at time X), but there is no need for it to know how that state was reached or how the state will change in the next timestep.

The responsibility of `PhysicsSystem` would then be to change the state of the world from time X to X+1 according to certain rules. In order to do that, `PhysicsSystem` needs to have a reference to the `PhysicalWorld` that it can query (which objects are there, which objects are present within a radius R of object O, etc.) and make changes to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea behind the model was to iterative through the `PhysicsSystems`-list in the `PhysicsWorld` and therefore call the `update()`-method of each individual system. To my understanding, the implementation itself is then hidden from the `PhysicsWorld`.


Also, I thought a `PhysicsWorld` would contain different `PhysicsSystems` rather than every `PhysicsSystem` containing the same `PhysicsWorld`. Is there a flaw behind this thought?

Comment: How do you think it would work that multiple PhysicsSystems make changes to the same world, independent of each other.